# Python SMTP safety

Tags: python, email, smtp

I would like to use Python's SMTP library to send emails, but I'm wondering whether there is any security issue of doing so. For staying in the safe side, I was thinking of using a service like outlook who have proper certification.

There is a server.starttls before I do server.login(...). I'm not exactly sure what that does. I'm decent at Python, but not so proficient in mail security. Could anyone explain to me what comprises may occur going through the SMTP library?

Edit my Code is as follows

```py
    server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp-mail.outlook.com",587)
    server.starttls()
    server.login("mysuername","mypassword")
    ##I write my email content here
    server.quit()
```

Comment: you can read result of starttls() and it should have response code 220 as statet in RFC (https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3207). If you receive 454 or 501, it is not safe to send your credentials. So read it. What it does is, when you open connection to server and you send starttls, if server supports it, it opens an encrypted layer inside your connection and all following commands should then be encrypted.